# runing a programm offline

Tags: linux, command-line

Is there a way to run a programm offline on linux ?
I recently discovered that a program I'm using is sending a lot of undesired packets on the network.
I still want to use this programm but I want to use it offline. How can I do that ? (without having to remove my ethernet cable, I just want this program in particular to be offline, not my whole computer)
This is how I run my programm `./my_programm.AppImage`. So maybe, I need to contenerized my app. **BUT** I can't do that, since it's using way too much services that it's gonna take me weeks to dockerized it.
From what I read, there's probably something to do with groups but I haven't been able to make it works.

EDIT : This issue has been solved with `sudo unshare -n ./my_programm.AppImage`

Comment: It entirely depends on the application.

Comment: lets says I'm running it like this : `python3 script.py`, how would I do ?

Comment: `man 7 network_namespaces`, [`firejail --net=none …`](https://firejail.wordpress.com).

Comment: Rather that look at how to stop the traffic, I would be looking first as to why, where and what data it is sending and determine whether that is normal. If it is normal, blocking the traffic may stop the software running correctly.

Comment: @Vincent - You want to block just that single python script or all Python processes?

Comment: edit : I solved it with `unshare -n ./my_program`